# WP_Query posts_per_page strange caching

Tags: wp-query

I want to make custom query loop with posts_per_page limit.

```
<?php
    $news = get_category_by_slug('news');

    $sidebar_related = new WP_Query([
            'category__not_in' => [$news->term_id],
            'post__not_in' => [$post->ID],
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
    ]);

    if($sidebar_related->have_posts()) :
        while($sidebar_related->have_posts()) : 
            $sidebar_related->the_post();

            the_title();

        endwhile; 

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

This code returns me 10 (or another value) posts instead of 4.

`$sidebar_related->request` shows

> "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND
>   wp_posts.ID NOT IN (15190) AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id
>   FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (620) ) ) AND
>   wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
>   GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 4"

As you can see, there is LIMIT 4. But 
`$sidebar_related->posts` shows Array with 11 elements.

1. I've tried remove all plugins: **nothing happens**
2. I've tried to install my theme on empty blog: **works correctly**
3. I've tried to remove all caches (object cache, wp_query cache): **nothing happens**
4. I've tried to change `category__not_in` arg to `category__in`: **works correctly**
5. Add `wp_reset_postdata();` before the loop: **nothing happens**

So I can't understand why it works this way. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found the reason.

We must ignore **sticky posts** in WP_Query this way:

```
 $sidebar_related = new WP_Query([
            'category__not_in' => [$news->term_id],
            'post__not_in' => [$post->ID],
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
    ]);
```

I hope it will help somebody.